# SQL Query - ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

```
rs.Open "SELECT [A$].Security,[A$].Name,SUM([A$].[Price]) FROM [A$] INNER JOIN [B$] ON [A$].Security = [B$].ID GROUP BY [A$].Security,[A$].Description", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
```

The result that I get from this query does not align or match the respective ID in sheet B. For Example :- A is the master worksheet from where I aggregate records matching the ID of B and Security of A. Now, A might have multiple instances of B's ID having different price, which is the reason why I aggregate. My question is that when I paste the record set data, I see that the aggregated price value is not pasted in front of the ID in B i.e I want them to be ordered according to the ID in B and ORDER BY also doesn't work, throwing an error that [B$].ID is not a part of the aggregate function. Can someone hint on how can it be done ?

Comment: Do the IDs on sheet B have a natural ordering - ascending/descending - or are they ordered in some other way?

Comment: The ID's that start with a letter comes first and then ascending order of number, but one point is that some B's are not present in A, so they should be kept blank and so I cannot copy paste it directly as a record which is not in A should be empty but instead it will have data if  I just copy paste it. I am thinking about an matching algorithm but stuck on if loops could work.

Comment: The ascending sort order using ADO with Excel is numbers first followed by text so 7, banana, 4, apple would sort to 4, 7, apple, banana. This doesn't match what you're looking for so you would either have to live with the default sort order or add an additional column to B which specifies the position of each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
rs.Open "SELECT [B$].ID, [A$].Name, SUM([A$].[Price]) FROM [B$] LEFT JOIN [A$] ON [B$].ID = [A$].Security GROUP BY [B$].ID, [A$].Name", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
```

This should give you the total price for each ID in B and will include the IDs from B which have no entries in A. Every non-aggregated column in the SELECT clause has to appear in the GROUP BY clause so because you are selecting ID and Name, both of those are in the GROUP BY clause. If there are multiple names for the same ID then this won't work correctly as you'll get multiple lines per ID.

Maintaining the same order as the entries in B isn't possible unless you either sort B by the natural sort order which ADO uses or add an additional column to B that you could use in an ORDER BY clause